Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) in vite.config.ts
I'm trying to use shadcn inside a react vite project, this is my vite.config.ts :
import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: "autoUpdate",
      includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "apple-touch-icon.png", "mask-icon.svg"],
      injectRegister: false,

      pwaAssets: {
        disabled: false,
        config: true,
      },

      manifest: {
        name: "z-hot",
        short_name: "zhot",
        description: "web app for company profile z-hot",
        theme_color: "#16a34a",
        icons: [
          {
            src: "pwa-64x64.png",
            sizes: "64x64",
            type: "image/png",
          },
          {
            src: "pwa-192x192.png",
            sizes: "192x192",
            type: "image/png",
          },
          {
            src: "pwa-512x512.png",
            sizes: "512x512",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "any",
          },
          {
            src: "maskable-icon-512x512.png",
            sizes: "512x512",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "maskable",
          },
        ],
      },

      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ["**/*.{js,css,html,svg,png,ico}"],
        cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
        clientsClaim: true,
      },

      devOptions: {
        enabled: false,
        navigateFallback: "index.html",
        suppressWarnings: true,
        type: "module",
      },
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    environment: "happy-dom",
    setupFiles: "./src/tests/setup.ts",
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://z-hot.vercel.app/",
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});


As well as my package.json :
{
  "name": "z-hot-client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "generate-pwa-assets": "pwa-assets-generator --preset minimal public/logo.svg"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.4.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.62.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.6.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "embla-carousel": "^8.5.1",
    "embla-carousel-autoplay": "^8.5.1",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.5.1",
    "happy-dom": "^15.11.7",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "lucide-react": "^0.468.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.54.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.4.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^7.0.2",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.5",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "vitest": "^2.1.8",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.15",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.17.0",
    "@vite-pwa/assets-generator": "^0.2.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^9.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.49",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.16",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.10",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.20.0",
    "workbox-core": "^7.1.0",
    "workbox-window": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "sharp": "0.32.6",
    "sharp-ico": "0.1.5"
  }
}


as well as my tsconfig.json :
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}


in my tsconfig.json i have try add "types": ["node"], and got another error like this:
"Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptionsts"
when i run pnpm build i don't get any errors and the build process runs fine
What seems to be the issue?
I hope the code in my vite.config.ts doesn't get any errors because I have followed the shadcn installation method properly

Have you tried npm i @types/node?
